# How to check xpath element exist in webpage using workfusion studio?

Tags: automation, rpa, workfusion

Check xpath element exist in opened webpage using workfusion studio conditional action.

Currently i'm using webelement Actions Library to login on specific website. its working fine.

But when i already logined then its give me an error on login steps because its redirected on home page directly.

So, I want to check if Xpath element is exist on my webpage or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish a check, you can create an Exception Handling block, and put a Mouse Click by this XPath inside the "Try to complete” block.

Alternatively, you can use the Retry block or add more Wait time